# Deprecated on Send iOS debug build

Tags: codenameone

I've an old App that need some modifications.
It compiles and executes OK in my develop environment but when i send to iOS debug build i get this error:

Process return code is 0
Executing: javac -classpath /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build4740061127506876662xxx/classes -d /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build4740061127506876662xxx/classes /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build4740061127506876662xxx/stub/AlmoAppStub.java /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build4740061127506876662xxx/stub/AlmoAppStub.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
    private AlmoApp i = new AlmoApp();
            ^
  symbol:   class AlmoApp
  location: class AlmoAppStub
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build4740061127506876662xxx/stub/AlmoAppStub.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
    private AlmoApp i = new AlmoApp();
                            ^
  symbol:   class AlmoApp
  location: class AlmoAppStub
Note: /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build4740061127506876662xxx/stub/AlmoAppStub.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors
Process return code is 1

Yes... i've some deprecated code in my App (like FloatingHint, WebBrowser...) but if i send to Android build it compiles OK.
And... i've some old Apps that are compiling OK for iOS and for Android.

This error that i'm getting is relationed with the deprecated functions i'm using? 
(do i need to resolve first this deprecation use os some classes or could i do it progressively??)
If not... what should look for?

Thanks a lot
Ramon

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with deprecated code.

This means the generated code for iOS can't compile which means one of:

- You removed the public no argument constructor for `AlmoApp`
- You changed the package or name of the `AlmoApp` main class
- You removed the public denomination before `class AlmoApp`
- You added a throws statement to the constructor